# Change color of row before showing delete alert

Tags: jquery

When the delete button is clicked, I want to change the color of the row **first** and then display the delete confirmation alert. I tried doing it this way:

```
     /**
     * Removes the selected row.
     */
    $('.link-remove').on('click', function() {

        var parents = $(this).closest('tr');
        parents.css('background-color', '#ff6666'); //this doesn't work
        var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");


        if (result) {
           //do something on delete
        }
        return false;

    });
```

But this doesn't change the color at all.

When I try changing the background color of the row on successful deletion, it works:

```
$.post(
        ajaxurl,
        data,
        function( response )
            {
                //alert(response);
                console.log(response);
                console.log("Success");
                parents.css('background-color', '#ff6666'); //this works
            }
    );
```

But I would like to highlight the row before the confirmation shows rather than after deletion.

How can I achieve this effect? And is it possible to achieve the effect without `setTimeout`?

**EDIT:**
HTML:

```
<div class="some-data">
<input
        class="some_class"
        id="id_of_the_elem"
        name="name_of_the_elem"
        type="text"
        value="some_value" />

<div style="display:inline-block;">
            <a class="link-remove" href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your HTML ?

Comment: your code should work, i think there is some console error, please check

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I checked, there is no console error.

Comment: where is tr , table in updated html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `setTimeout` with your html and working Snippet.I add table for this purpose. If I am wrong  please comment.

```js
  $('.link-remove').on('click', function() {

        var parents = $(this).closest('tr');
        parents.css('background-color', '#ff6666'); //this is working :)
        setTimeout(function () {
                 var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
             }, 500);
                  

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr><td>
<div class="some-data">
<input
        class="some_class"
        id="id_of_the_elem"
        name="name_of_the_elem"
        type="text"
        value="some_value" />

<div style="display:inline-block;">
            <a class="link-remove" href="#">123<i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Settimeout is asynchronous and is put into javascript event loop. It will be called at the end once all code is executed. So `if(result)` will not be available.

```
 /**
 * Removes the selected row.
 */
$('.link-remove').on('click', function() {

    var parents = $(this).closest('tr');
    parents.css('background-color', '#ff6666');
    var result;
    var secondsDelay = 2; //2 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
       if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
          // Do your code here
       }
    }, secondsDelay * 1000);

    return false;

});
```

Comment: if result is asynchronous still it should change background color right?

Comment: Yes it should change the color.

Comment: My question was that it is not changing the color. Even if I remove the `setTimeout` function to show the delete confirmation alert without any delay, it doesn't change the background color of the parent.

Comment: We can't checkout without seeing the actual dom